# How to insert multiple data sources in an underscore.js template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, underscore.js

I'm using dataTables and underscore.js. Here are my datatable columns:

```
{
    data: 'date', searchable: false, orderable: false,
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return row.date;
    }
},
{
    data: 'routeSectionStepID', searchable: false, orderable: false,
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        var structure = _.template($('#tmpl-actions').html()),
            html = structure({ Id: data });
        return html;
    }
}
```

And here's my underscore template:

```
<script id="tmpl-actions" type="text/html">

    <form action="">
        <% if (date == null){ %>
            <input type="checkbox" name="process" value="<%= Id %>" id="checkbox" checked disabled/>Id: <%= Id %>
        <% } else { %>
            <input type="checkbox" name="process" value="<%= Id %>" id="checkbox" />Id: <%= Id %>
        <% } %>
    </form>

</script>
```

As you can see in the if statement above, I'm trying to make the checkbox enabled/disabled based on whether or not the 'date' column is empty. Obviously just typing 'date' in the if statement doesn't work.

I think I need the `html = structure({ Id: data });` line in my first example to say `Id: data` AND `Date: data` but obviously they can't both use the same `data`.

How do I access the previous column's `date` data and pass it (along with `routeSectionStepId`) into my _.template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

`html = structure({ Id: data, Date: row.date });`

and

`<% if (Date == null){ %>`